# StringReader formatted string

Tags: c#, string, format, stringreader

I have followed [this Wordpress tutorial](http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/print-from-a-listbox-using-c) which works great. I have used a listview and when i try to format the string it doesn't recognise the `\t` (but does recognise `\n`). It also won't recognise `String.Format` etc.

Is there anyway that I can format the string using tabs or something similar?

Cheers

**EDIT**

```
for( i = 0; i < lstView.Items.Count;i++) 
{ 
    name = lstView.Items[i].Text; 
    state = lstView.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text; 
    country = lstView.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text; 
    line += name + "\t" + state + "\t" + country + "\n"; 
}  
StringReader reader = new StringReader(line);
```

When line is used to print the string is joined together so the \t doesn't work. The \n for a new line does work though. Does anyone know any way that I can format the string without using spaces.

The result is like this

NameStateCountry

LongernameStateCountry

anotherNameAnotherStateAnotherCountry

Where I would like them lined up (like in a table) with name one column, state another column and country then third

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide a small code sample? Or clarify the question a bit?

Comment: How do you know it's not recognizing the tabs? In some contexts, tabs are not printed.  In other words, the string "a\tb" appears as "ab" rather than "a   b"

Comment: DO you want to remove the \t and \n from the text that comes from Listveiw.. Please elaborate on what u want, especially what do u mean by formatting the string and where u want it to be formatted and how.

Comment: how do I get it formatted like code in this comment box?

Comment: Put it in an answer instead. The help link to the right of the text edit box (when editing a comment) describes mini-markup used in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a bit odd that tabs are lost, but on the other hand, tabs will probably be problematic if the individual string elements (name, state etc.) varies in length.
What you could do instead is use `string.Format()` and use fixed column widths.
To get nice visual output this would include a parse step to determine the correct column width.
When this is done, use something like this to use spaces instead of tabs.

```
string line = string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}", "name", "state", "country");
```

**EDIT**: Saw that you did not want to use spaces.
In this case, you will probably need to handle this in the printing algorithm itself. You could still separate items with tabs, then for each line split it on tabs, creating an array of items (columns) per line.
For each item, print it using `Graphics.DrawString()` with a suitable X-position offset.

See the documentation for [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3thd43b%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this originally but I obviously did something wrong, but works great now.